# Merge section polygons in PLSS

Tags: python, polygon, dissolve

I am trying to merge quarter quarter sections of polygons from PLSS into a quarter section.
However, I also want it assigned to correct Township/Range/Section while merging.
I know I can hand merge all of them using the Editing tool, but since I will have to do to the entire state of Kansas.
I was thinking of writing a script to help.  The problem is that the Township/Range/Section field in the attribute table is in one field and I don't know how to do that when is all together.

I will need to merge those four polygon that belong to the same Township/Range/Sec/qtr as following:
01S01E01NWNE
01S01E01NWNW
01S01E01NWSE
01S01E01NWSW

and I need to leave in 01S01E01NWNW.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though you are using the [USGDR data (BLM)](http://www.usgdr.org/PLSS.aspx)

BTW: Dissolve is what you would use instead of merge.
the python part is not my thing.
The dissolve command with the first division identifier column as the
dissolve field should get you what you want
First you want to create a new field to hold the qtr section value for each qtr qtr by using ...
right ([SECDIVNO],2)
**{sorry vbscript is how I have to do it until I learn python}**
Then run the dissolve on firstdivid

Second Division Identifier  -   WY060480N1030W0SN310ASESW
First Division Identifier  -    WY060480N1030W0SN310

[image]